# netstat shows many "Established" connections by libpepflashplayer.so . Should I be worried?

Tags: 14.04, netstat

I fired `netstat -tpn | grep -i established` and it shows many occurrences of libflashplayer connecting to external IPs. 
What are all these?

P.S - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting. You can easily do whatever redactions you need on text.

Comment: Are you running any Chrome/Chromium windows? Playing Flash video?

Comment: @muru - Have removed the screenshot. :) 
May I know the reason for no screenshot posting ??

Comment: @BharadwajRaju - Yes I am using Chromium but no video (or flash related activity) is being performed in any of the tabs.

Comment: @v1h5 The reason for actual text being preferred over screenshots of text is to 1. help those who have visual difficulties 2. Make post easier to search and index 3. Make it easier to read.

Comment: Ok. I will surely keep this in mind next time. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju : I searched for IP that is being contacted by libpepflashplayer and there are only two domains being hosted on that ip. 
`multibaggerstockideas.com` and `alphayoga.org` . This is so strange. Why is my ubuntu establishing connections with them.

Comment: I'd asked for the output in text. :) Anyway, the PID is listed in the output, so you can use `pstree -psa <pid>` to get the parent processes